# Swift showing Promo Code View for In App purchase not doing anything

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, promotion-code

I tried adding a function for **Promo-Codes** so I can give some users something for free.

I created a Promo-Code inside **App Store Connect** and this is my function to open the `PromoCodeView`:

```
@objc func promoCodeButtonTapped() {
    let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        paymentQueue.presentCodeRedemptionSheet()
    }
}
```

The view is presented properly. However I can't do anything there. I can type in a code or cancel but I can not confirm or anything. What am I missing here?? I am running it on the live-version btw. I know I can not test it in development.

The App is live! If you want to test it yourself:

https://apps.apple.com/de/app/wishlists-einfach-w%C3%BCnschen/id1503912334

**Generated Promo Code for the In-App Purchase:**

> HE9T64F74JHT

If one can make it work, he can get Premium of my app for free with this code :D (Profile -> Premium Membership -> Promo Code )

[image]

Comment: I entered the code and pressed "enter" on the keyboard and I get an error that the code is invalid. Presumably it has already been redeemed. Does pressing enter with a valid code not then present a purchase on your payment observer?

Comment: @Paulw11 inside my app?? this does not work for me. Pressing enter does absolutley nothing

Comment: Hmm. I installed your app just now and when I paste the code and tap "return" I get https://imgur.com/a/fuZG4uy

Comment: @Paulw11 can you try this code: "RH6KFN3M6KRL" . I just created it so it must be 100% correct

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: @Paulw11 ok, but why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think your code should be `SKPaymentQueue.default.presentCodeRedemptionSheet()` - You should access the singleton instance of the payment queue.

Comment: @Paulw11 in the latest update I am actually calling it like this

Comment: So the code that is running isn't the code shown in your question now?

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a slight misunderstanding of how promo codes work, and to be honest, it is a little confusing on Apple's part.

`presentCodeRedemptionSheet` is only used to redeem promo codes associated with an auto-renewing subscription.  Promo codes for other IAP types are redeemed through the App Store app.  Since your IAP is a non-consumable this applies to your app.

I was able to redeem the code you supplied using the following process:

1. Access my account in the App Store app (Tap my picture in the top right corner)
2. Select "Redeem gift card or code"
3. Paste the code
4. Open your app and receive the "Thanks for the beer" message (Since the redemption is simply presented to your payment queue observer as a purchase).
5. There does seem to be an issue with your code, however, as I can't change my profile picture and I get an error that I need to be a premium user.
6. I tried to purchase the upgrade directly and got a message from Apple that it was free since I already owned it; but I am still a Llama :(

You can remove the "Promo code" button from your UI; It isn't applicable in your case.

Comment: I am sorry that you're still a Lama :D I have some Keychain bug since the last Update... Anyway I will fixt it in the next update! To my question: I definitely isunderstood how promo codes work, thanks for your explanation!